# flutter_facebook_login and AWS: Invalid login token. Not a valid OpenId Connect identity token

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, amazon-cognito, flutter-facebook-login

I am new to Flutter and AWS and I made a small project with facebook authentication.
using:

- amazon_cognito_identity_dart: ^0.0.22
- flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0

On AWS I:

- Configured an API with a POST method
- Created a new Cognito User Pool
- Created a new App Client in the new Cognito User Pool
- Created a new Cognito Identity Pool with Facebook AppID from Facebook

I have a sign in function

```
signInFacebook() async {
    final facebookLoginResult = await signInWithFacebook();
    final credentials = new Credentials(
      cognitoIdentityPoolId,
      cognitoUserPoolId,
      cognitoClientId,
      facebookLoginResult.accessToken.token
    );
```

a method signInWithFacebook:

```
import 'package:flutter_facebook_login/flutter_facebook_login.dart';

Future<FacebookLoginResult> signInWithFacebook() async {
  final facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
  final facebookLoginResult = await facebookLogin.logIn(['email']);
  return facebookLoginResult;
}
```

a class Credentials:

```
import 'package:amazon_cognito_identity_dart/cognito.dart';

class Credentials {
  final CognitoCredentials _cognitoCredentials;
  final String _token;

  Credentials(String identityPoolId, String userPoolId, String clientId, this._token)
      : _cognitoCredentials = new CognitoCredentials(identityPoolId, new CognitoUserPool(userPoolId, clientId));

  Future<CognitoCredentials> get cognitoCredentials async {
    await _cognitoCredentials.getAwsCredentials(_token);
    return _cognitoCredentials;
  }
}
```

and a credentials.dart with the Cognito credentials and the endpoint of the API

The problem is when it executes the method:

```
    await _cognitoCredentials.getAwsCredentials(_token);
```

I get the following error:

```
 CognitoClientException{statusCode: 400, code: NotAuthorizedException, name: NotAuthorizedException, message: Invalid login token. Not a valid OpenId Connect identity token.}
```

**Why is the token I receive from facebook not valid?
Am I missing something?**

Answer (score 1):

i solved updating to the

```
  amazon_cognito_identity_dart_2: ^0.1.19
```

and using the method

```
await _cognitoCredentials.getAwsCredentials(_token, 'graph.facebook.com');
```